# Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: swift, constructor, unwrap

I define a class in Swift like that:

```
class RecordedAudio: NSObject {
    var title: String!
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!

    init(title: String, filePathUrl: NSURL) {
        self.title = title
        self.filePathUrl = filePathUrl
    }
}
```

After that, I declare the global var of this one in controller

```
var recordedAudio: RecordedAudio!
```

And then, create the instance in this function:

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if(flag){
            // save recorded audio
           recordedAudio = RecordedAudio(title: recorder.url.lastPathComponent, filePathUrl: recorder.url)
...
```

But I got the error message in line I create the instance of RecordedAudio:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Could you help me this case? I am a beginner of Swift...

Comment: recorder.url.lastPathComponent probably returns a String?, which is an optional String. Your constructor takes a String (not optional). Therefore, you need to unwrap your optional String in order to use it to create the RecordedAudio

Comment: You right @WillM. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastPathComponent` returns an optional String:

[image]

but your `RecordedAudio` seems to require `String` not `String?`.
There are two easy ways to fix it:

Add `!` in case you are sure lastPathComponent will never return nil

```
recordedAudio = RecordedAudio(title: recorder.url.lastPathComponent!, filePathUrl: recorder.url)
```

or

Use a default title in case lastPathComponent is nil

```
recordedAudio = RecordedAudio(title: recorder.url.lastPathComponent ?? "Default title", filePathUrl: recorder.url)
```